# combine streams with rxjs (with switch map and take)

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have 2 streams, from keyboard events (K) and from mouse events (M).
Keyboard events should be produced when previous event was null or mouse event.
Mouse events should be produced when previous event was keyboard event.

So dispatching M-K-M-K-K-M-K-K, should invoke keyboard handler 3 times and mouse handler 2 times.

Following subscription allow keyboard stream to produce multiple keyboard events which is not what I want.

```
keyboardStream(document)
        .do(keyboardHandler)
        .switchMap(() => mouseStream(document).take(1))
        .subscribe(mouseHandler)
```

Comment: You say _Mouse events should be produced when previous event was keyboard event._ so how can your events start with `M`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended with:

```
const keyboard$ = fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
.pipe(
    mapTo('k')
);

const mouseOnce$ = fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
        switchMap(() => fromEvent(document, 'mousedown').pipe(first())),
        mapTo('m')
    );

const stream = merge(
    mouseOnce$,
    keyboard$
).pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
```